# Is VML supported in the MVC Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vml

I have injected some custom javascript into my MVC application that uses VML to perform some graphic rendering of objects containing text. Works great in HTML pages but when I used the script in my MVC app I received only the text with no graphics, and the text which should have been contained in each of the rendered objects was overlayed in the upper left coordinate of the page in IE8. Not very legible at all.

In Firefox, The objects were rendered but all the text was rendered with the same overlay results in the lower left coordinate of the page.

Does anyone know if VML works with ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VML is a browser-based technology that has been supported primarily on Internet Explorer. The Framework that the web application runs under (ASP.NET, MVC, etc) has no bearing on it.

Comment: Thanks. I determined that the following tag which is automatically embedded into my MVC ASP.NET application was scrambling the results. Once I commented the tag out, all the rendered elements showed up fine.

    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">